# Removing css from link image

Tags: css

Our designer created this css for links

```
A
{
   text-decoration: underline;
    color: #E77C15;
}

A:link
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #E77C15;
}

A:visited
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #E77C15;
}

A:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #039;
}

A:active
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #E77C15;
}
```

I need an image link with no border around it. Right now it has a border of the color from the css around it.

I have tried

```
   <a href='myurl' style="border-style:none; text-decoration:none" >
         <img src="myimage.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px" alt="Remove" title="Remove" />
   </a>
```

but the border still shows.
How can I remove the border around this link image.
Thanks!

Comment: set `border:0` in image `style`

Comment: Lol, everybody answered the same.

Comment: @midas: Everyone gets an up vote:) clearly I am not a css guy. I do almost all desktop apps so have forgotten all my css.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that's the right thing to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add the CSS to `<img>`, not to `<a>`.

Better use a general CSS rule:

```
img { border:none }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a img {
   border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `border:none;` on the `img`.

```
a img{
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following rule to your CSS:

```
a img {
  border: 0;
}
```

I'd encourage you, or your designer, to look into using [CSS Reset Stylesheets](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Answer (score 1):

Place this in your stylesheet:

```
a img {border:0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The border is around the image, not the link.

Add:

```
a img {
 border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your CSS:

a img{
    border:none;
    }